# Recursive CTE without inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I wonder if the pseudo query below is possible to be made with RTE (recursive CTE).
The main idea is, that the last part of the query (cte3, cte4) would still have more queries (cte5,cte6,etc) but the main idea is that:

```
SELECT * FROM [previous dataset result]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [full result]
WHERE statusId = [previous used status id] - 1
 id IS NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [previous dataset result])
```

I have tried using `INNER JOIN` as such a normal RTE but it doesn't gives the expected result. An `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the RTE should give a correct result (theoretically) but since RTE won't accept `OUTER JOIN`'s, I'm kinda stuck.

Here is what I am using at the moment (CTE without the recursive part):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    // query
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte
    WHERE WorkOrderStatusID = 8
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM cte
    WHERE SPStatus=9
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM cte
    WHERE WorkOrderStatusID=7
    AND OrderSPMovableID NOT IN (SELECT OrderSPMovableID FROM cte2)
), cte4 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte3
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM cte
    WHERE WorkOrderStatusID=6
    AND OrderSPMovableID NOT IN (SELECT OrderSPMovableID FROM cte3)
)
SELECT * FROM cte4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
Sample data:

```
Id  WorkOrderStatusID   OrderSPMovableID 
1       7                   12345
2       8                   12345
3       8                   11111
4       6                   11111
5       4                   23411
6       7                   23411
7       3                   43215
8       1                   34567
9       5                   76543
```

Expected Result:

```
Id  WorkOrderStatusID   OrderSPMovableID 
2       8                   12345
3       8                   11111
6       7                   23411
7       3                   43215
8       1                   34567
9       5                   76543
```

So, in short, from the complete data result, I want to get the data with highest `WorkOrderStatusID`. Due to the actual result would have around 20 fields, I found `group` to be a bit hard to use and verify, thus I am taking the Recursive CTE approach, if possible.

Comment: I don't find your current example/commentary easy to follow to understand what result set you're actually trying to construct. Could you add some sample data and expected results to your question please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , I have edited the question to include some sample data and expected results. I hope it gives you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Huh? You basically want, for each `OrderSPMovableID`, to select the row with the highest `WorkOrderStatusID` value? That's trivial to achieve with a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) based query - or am I misunderstanding what you're looking for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It wasn't actually what I had in mind at first, due to some conditions, but I think you are right, it could work using a `ROW_NUMBER()` solution. But, just out of curiosity, would it actually be possible to also achieve using RTE's?

Comment: A plain old correlated subquery is all you need here: `select * from #t t1 where WorkOrderStatusID = (select max(WorkOrderStatusID) from #t t2 where t1.OrderSPMovableID=t2.OrderSPMovableID)`